# Unity run XR mode in windowed mode on Hololens 2

Tags: unity-game-engine, hololens

I want to run XR function with windowed mode on Hololens 2.
However, if I enable XR Plug-in Management : Initialize XR on Startup, it would run in fullscreen.
I try to disable this checkbox and init XR at the runtime but it still run in fullscreen.
I had setted `Screen.fullScreen = false` but it didn't work either.
Does anyone know how to run XR function with windowed mode on Hololens 2?
Thanks in advance for any suggestions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unity XR pipelines are designed to create Immersive view apps, and most Holographic API and input system(such as eye-tracking and hand-tracking) will be invalid in 2D views. For 2D view apps please create a UWP XAML app from Visual Studio. More information please see: [2D views](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/mixed-reality/design/app-views#2d-views)